# Bug in fminf and fmaxf on iOS 64bit processors

Tags: ios, 64-bit, arm64

I came across a bug with the 64bit processors that I wanted to share.

```
CGFloat test1 = 0.58;
CGFloat test2 = 0.40;
CGFloat value;

value = fmaxf( test1, test2 );
```

The result would be:
value = 0.5799999833106995

This obviously is a rounding issue, but if you needed to check to see which value was picked you would get an erroneous result.

```
if( test1 == value ){
 // do something
}
```

however if you use either MIN( A, B ) or MAX( A, B ) it would work as expected. 
I thought this is was worth sharing

Thanks

Comment: Please see answers below as this is not a bug, but a bug with my code. Stephen thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It is not a but in your code, is is just an example of display rounding due to a display precision to small to show all the digits. With a display  format of `%0,20f` all of the resoles are displayed without rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a bug in `fminf` or `fmaxf`.  There is a bug in your code.

On 64-bit systems, `CGFloat` is typedef'd to `double`, but you're using the `fmaxf` function, which operates on `float` (not `double`), which causes its arguments to be rounded to single precision, thus changing the value.  Don't do that.

On 32-bit systems, this doesn't happen because `CGFloat` is typedef'd to `float`, matching the argument and return type of `fmaxf`; no rounding occurs.

Instead, either include `<tgmath.h>` and use `fmax` without the `f` suffix, or use `float` instead of `CGFloat`.

Comment: CGFLoat maps to a double on 64 bit iOS devices? I did not know that! Thanks for that. That implies that the 64 bit ARM has native double precision math. That's cool.

Comment: 32-bit ARM (or at least the implementations used in high-end phones) has native double-precision too.

Comment: 0.58 can not be represented exactly by a CGFloat. How you see it depends on how it is displayed. The reason is because of the different bases of the number systems: base 10 for decimal, base 2 for CGFloat. So while this answer does have some correct information it is incorrect.

Comment: @Zaph: while it's true that 0.58 cannot be represented exactly, that's not the source of the problem that the questioner was having (if it were, he would have experienced the issue one 32-bit as well).

Comment: If the values had been displayed with a higher precision, %0.20f, none of the floats/doubles would have been displayed as exact values due to rounding. The rounding occurs at a different display precision doe to the type double or float. If you start out with an approximation you will end up with an approximation. Try it.

Comment: @Zaph: the problem isn't that the value isn't exact; the problem is that because two different types are in use, 0.58 is rounded to two different precisions, which results in two different values.

Comment: @Stephen I understand that but the bigger problem is not understanding why the results were displayed rounded or not. Your solution leads one to believe that with the change the numbers will be exact, that is not the case.

Comment: The question isn’t about display; it is about the `fmaxf` function and equality comparison.  It can be (and was) answered without discussing rounding for display.  Some people may or may not understand rounding floating point numbers for assignment and printing, but those issues are outside the scope of this question.  One can’t simply answer every question involving floating point with “floating point isn’t exact”, but feel free to add your own answer if you want to.

Comment: I tried Stephen's solution and it seemed to solve my problem. One thing that did throw me, is that we are meant to use CGFloat instead of float as it is processor independent and the right type for the float would be selected for the processor. So I would have thought that fmaxf should not return float but CGFloat so that it would not cause issues. But obviously it does not and looking at the header files it returns float.

Comment: @reza23: `fmaxf` is defined by the C standard (which has no notion of `CGFloat`), and it’s argument and return type is required to be `float`.  Using the `tgmath.h` functions that are overloaded to support both `float` and `double` is definitely the best solution.

Comment: @Stephen: In the math.h there is the function "extern double fmax(double, double);" which returns double and not CGFloat. Would this cause issues with 32bit processor?

Comment: Not if you include `tgmath.h` instead of `math.h`.